# Nested if statements or And

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Is a nested statement or the use of and in an if statement would be more efficient?

Basically is:

```
if condition1:
    if condition2:
        #do stuff
```

or

```
if condition1 and condition2:
    #do stuff
```

more efficient or are they similar on performance and for the sake of readability which should I choose to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer: no

`dis` disassemblers python module to bytecode that being executed by interpreter. For both functions number of executed operations is the same (10)

But generally preferred to use `and` clause because of better code readability and less nesting

## Code:

```
>>> def test_inner_if(condition1=True, condition2=True):
...     if condition1:
...         if condition2:
...             pass
...         
>>> def test_and_if(condition1=True, condition2=True):
...     if condition1 and condition2:
...         pass
...     
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test_inner_if)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (condition1)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
  3           4 LOAD_FAST                1 (condition2)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
  4     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(test_and_if)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (condition1)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (condition2)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
  3     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

2nd one is generally preferred. In terms of run time they wouldn't make really any noticeable difference, but in terms of readability of code (good code is easily readable) the second one is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Just go for readability
If you're trying to  do something easy like x>3 and x<30 just use on if.
If your conditions are function calls probably use multiple ifs as it will be easier to read and easier to debug

Answer (score 1):

The best piece of advice I have gotten in terms of optimization is,

"find the slowest part of your code and optimize the heck out of that"

The context of the if statements matter, so for example in one case they can be deep inside 3 or more for loops, then going for good optimization (and comment you logic) would be good. In another case though, you may determining whether to throw an error at the beginning of a function. In that case readability is critical.

Secondly, how you optimize is important too. The interpreter way see both way as equivalent which means that it is best to go for readability. One easy way to find out is to use this

```
import time 

s = time.clock()

#your code here

print(time.clock() - s) #shows how long the code segment took to run
```

This can be an interesting experiment whenever you have an optimization question.